# Android: setOnItemClickListener doesn't work for ListView in soft keyboard

Tags: android, android-listview, android-softkeyboard

I am developing a custom soft keyboard for Android. I have added a list on the top of the normal keyboard. The list is just a normal ListView. What I need to do is to detect and respond to the click event inside the main program, which is **SoftKeyboard.java**. The ListView is initialised inside onCreateCandidatesView() method. Here's my code.

**suggestion_list.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ListView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:background="@color/candidate_background"
    android:divider="#BBCFCFCF"
    android:dividerHeight="1dp"
    android:drawSelectorOnTop="false" />
```

**SoftKeyboard.java**

```
public class SoftKeyboard extends InputMethodService 
        implements KeyboardView.OnKeyboardActionListener {

    //dummy data for the list
    private static final String[] items = {"1","2","3"};
    //some other variables

    @Override 
    public View onCreateCandidatesView() {     
        LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        ListView ls = (ListView)mInflater.inflate(R.layout.suggestion_list,null);

        ls.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,items));

        ls.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                Log.v("index", "Clicked");
            }
        });

        return ls;
    }

    //some other methods
}
```

But The ListView doesn't seem to respond to the setOnItemClickListener() at all. Could anyone kindly help me on this issue? Thanks a lot!

---

**Update:**

I found that even if I use a normal ListView, it still doesn't work. I updated my code above for using a normal ListView.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding

`android:descendantFocussability=blocksDescendants` to the top most linear layout.It might work.

Comment: you haven't posted your ListView extended class' full source code yet

Comment: Hi, I just added my complete CandidateView class code to the post

Comment: I found that the issue seemed not related to CandidateView. Even if I replaced it with a normal ListView, the issue still exists. I have updated my code for using a normal ListView. I think there must be something strange with the softkeyboard.

Comment: Is it required for you to have the click listener in the keyborad class? Why cant be it done in the activity?

Comment: There is no activity for the softkeyboard. The whole thing is a SoftKeyboard class that extends InputMethodService

Comment: I have same issue, the ListView can response on onTouchEvent, but not on onItemClick event, don't know why.

Comment: I am having the same issue. OnItemClickListener works fine for Samsung 6, S7 edge, Moto X etc but it doesn't work for few devices such as S3 and LG G4. Not sure whats the relations. It doesn't look OS specific issue.